# Как мне из list получить list в формате JSON?

Tags: python, json

Мой код:

```
import json

pop = ['1', '2', '3']
tit = json.dumps(pop)
print(tit)
```

На выходе я получаю:

```
["\u0413\u043e\u0434", "\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f", "\u0421\u0428\u0410"]
```

А мне нужно получить в JSON:

```
['Год', 'Россия', 'США']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
tit = json.dumps(pop, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Пример:

```
In [26]: l = ['Год', 'Россия', 'США']

In [27]: json.dumps(l)
Out[27]: '["\\u0413\\u043e\\u0434", "\\u0420\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u044f", "\\u0421\\u0428\\u0410"]'

In [28]: json.dumps(l, ensure_ascii=False)
Out[28]: '["Год", "Россия", "США"]'
```

Comment: спасибо, а как сделать чтобы теперь и в console через js отображалось корректно, используя Ваш вариант, в console отображается ["[&quot;Год&quot;, &quot;Россия&quot;, &quot;США&quot;]"], как это исправить?